# How to force NumPy to always use a precision (float32, float64 ...)?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I am trying to study a little FIR example written in Python. See https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FIRFilter.html

My goal is to study how output precision varies for each `float16`, `float32` and `float64` (available in numpy). So for the first case I need to keep all my computations done in `float16` only. The thing is i should each time cast the data to ensure that I'm using the right format. Is there a method to consistently use a unified context for the whole computations i.e. to perform all computations (additions, substractions, cos, sin ...etc) using `float16` for example without re-writing code with casts?

Comment: one way to do it as a 1-time hassle, is to assign a dtype to all your operations using a variable, that you can then set and change at top of the file as needed.

Comment: See [Issue #6860: How to set float32 as default](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6860).

Answer (score 2):

From the [numpy basics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations):

> When operating with arrays of different types, the type of the
>   resulting array corresponds to the more general or precise one (a
>   behavior known as upcasting).

You can define the data type on the array creation. Applying a sum, multiplication or substraction, result will upcast to the "larger" type, it will also keep the dtype if you perform operations on the array, e.g.:

```
x = np.ones(10, dtype=np.float16)
y = np.ones(10, dtype=np.float32)
print((x + y).dtype, (x - y).dtype, (x * y).dtype)
print(np.sin(x).dtype, np.sin(y).dtype)
>> float32 float32 float32
   float16 float32
```

An exception is when passing an integer, in which case, by default, numpy upcasts to float64

```
print(np.sin(np.ones(10, dtype=int)).dtype)
>> float64
```

Comment: Isn't it the Sine function that does the upcasting? `a=np.array([1,1,1])`
`print(type(a[0]))` `<class 'numpy.int32'>`